# Add a new property/attribute at the product level and display it on the product detail page

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am new to Hybris. I want to add a new property/attribute at the product level and display it on the product detail page. What are the steps I have to follow to achieve this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You may find SAP Community forums or Super User more relevant for asking general questions about software usage.

Answer (score 1):

1. First you have to create a new attribute in the product model. You can either extend product model or create the new attribute in the existing item. https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/2105/en-US/8c755da8866910149c27ec908fc577ef.html will help you understand the type system.
2. You need to extend the populates and converters to bring this new attrinute from a service layer to facade layer. https://help.sap.com/viewer/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/2105/en-US/8b937ff886691014815fcd31ff1de47a.html?q=populators%20and%20converters will help you to understand how to extend a populator and convertor.
3. Once you have the product data object with the new attribute in the facade/ controller layer, rest is simple Spring code. You can add the new attribute in a Spring model object and display it in a .jsp page

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKlsww8eRLvPIZr6mNlMzGA/videos) youtebe channel, it has a lot of sample. Also you can find any education over platforms like Udemy.